# cannot find 'replicationfactor' in class org.mule.tools.model.anypoint.RuntimeFabricDeploymentSettings

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, anypoint-rtf, mule-maven-plugin

I cloned a flow from production that has Kafka Message Listener.
Replaced Kafka Message Listener with HTTP listener, so that I can load input payload and test it in local.

but when I click 'Test Connection' on  Listener configuration (localhost and 8082), I get an error "Test Connection failed"[info] Scanning for project..

Details error log from help tab says - "Cannot find 'replicationFactor' in class org.mule.tools.model.anypoint.RuntimeFabricDeploymentSettings

Can someone please help me in here

Comment: Please provide the flow and connector configuration as text XML and the full lines related to the error from the log. Don't use images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue probably is that, unrelated to your change, there has been a [change in the Mule Maven Plugin](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-maven-plugin/mule-maven-plugin-3.4.2-release-notes#features-and-functionality) used to deploy to Runtime Fabric:

```
replicationFactor was renamed to replicas, and now is nested under <runtimeFabricDeployment>.
```

You need to update the configuration of the plugin in the pom.xml to be compatible with newer versions of the plugin.